# Why does a cloned Flutter app not run on my phone?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run a Flutter app on my phone using VSC.

The app is a clone of this repository:
https://github.com/londonappbrewery/dicee-flutter

This is the error message I'm getting:
https://pastebin.com/MtGCSC98

(I tried to post the code on the post, but SO doesn't allow it since it's "too much code", then I posted only the link to pastebin and it said "too little code" smh. So, here are the first 4 rows...)

```
c:\Users\mudcip\Desktop\programming\flutter\dicee-flutter\lib>flutter run -v
[ +440 ms] executing: [C:\src\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[ +223 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +11 ms] 9b2d32b605630f28625709ebd9d78ab3016b2bf6
```

I tried to search other similar questions but found no solution.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you are running program from lib folder insted running from main project

Comment: Tried running it from main project folder and stumbled upon same error

Comment: its strange because it runs fine for me try command just "flutter run"

Comment: Still not working, I am running other apps without a problem. I'm using VSC.